# Generate strings larger than and lesser than

Tags: java, regex

I need to test my method which is validate input Strings larger and lesser than.
I already achieved something like that:

```
//given
var generex = new Generex("[a-zA-Z]{3,100}");
patientDtoIn.setFirstName(generex.random());
```

This regex generate Strings larger than 3 and lesser than 100. Including this 2 numbers too.
Now I need the opposite. "Lesser than 3 and larger than 100" excluding those 2 numbers. Could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,2}|[a-zA-Z]{101,})$
```

Pattern explanation:
`^` - match beginning of the string

`(?:...)` - non capturing group (used to group pattern)

`[a-zA-Z]{1,2}` - match pattern 1 or 2 times

`|` - alternation operator

`[a-zA-Z]{101,}` - match pattern 101 or more times

`$` - match end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fxv8tI/1)